Как при создании окна из сервиса окон, получить в него зависимости зарегистрированные в контейнере
Подскажите пожалуйста.
Столкнулся с небольшой наверно проблемой) не пойму как в созданное окно - сервисом окон получить автоматически зависимость из контейнера (потерялась связь с контейнером наверно).
Зарегистрировал зависимости и показал окно,  код:
public partial class App : Application
 {
     IServiceCollection _services;
     IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

     protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
     {
         base.OnStartup(e);

         _services = new ServiceCollection();
         ConfigureServices(_services);
         
         _serviceProvider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
         
         var loginWindow = _serviceProvider.GetService<LoginWindow>();
         loginWindow.Show();
     }

     void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddTransient<LoginWindow>(); 
         services.AddTransient<LoginViewModel>();

         services.AddScoped<IWindowService, WindowService>();

         services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
     }
 }

Далее в VM открытого окна прокидывается из контейнера сервис окон. В этой VM регистрирую в сервисе окон типы и показываю окно, код:
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICommand OpenSettingBDCommand { get; set; }

    IWindowService _windowService;
    public LoginViewModel(IWindowService windowService)
    {
        _windowService = windowService;

        Register();

        OpenSettingBDCommand = new Command(_ => { OpenSettingBD(); });
    }

    void Register() => _windowService.RegisterViewType<SettingBDViewModel, SettingBDWindow>();
    void OpenSettingBD()
    {
        SettingBDViewModel viewModel = new();
        _windowService.ShowModalView(viewModel);
    }

Здесь и началась проблемка, для созданного окно SettingBDWindow, SettingBDViewModel принимает еще один сервис, для проверки получения сервиса сделал так, код:
public class SettingBDViewModel : ViewModel
 {
     public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public SettingBDViewModel(ILoginService loginService)
     {
         Text = loginService.ToString();
     }
 }

В методе ниже инструкция конструктора требует сервис, которые ему нужен, но нужно же получать автоматически из контейнера., подумал я и сделал в конструкторе для аргумента конструктора = null, чтобы не сувать руками - new LoginService() в SettingBDViewModel viewModel = new();
void OpenSettingBD()
{
    SettingBDViewModel viewModel = new();
    _windowService.ShowModalView(viewModel);
}

Но все тщетно из контейнера, туда не попадает зависимость, как же можно поступить тогда:

Все таки руками внедрять сервис
Прокидывать провайдер, хотя нельзя или же обращаться к классу App, где лежит контейнером, чтобы дергать, нужный сервис
И есть еще идея, регистрировать в сервисе окон нетолько ViewModel и View, но и тут же сервис, чтобы все создавалось как надо.
Или может я что-то упустил, и все очень просто), подскажите пожалуйста.

Реализация сервиса окон как тут


Думайте про ответственность, у вас не должно быть разных ответственностей в классе. К примеру LoginViewModel - это что? VM окна логина? Если да, то ответственность - содержать и обрабатывать информацию самого окна, не более. А у вас она вдруг регистрирует другие окна, открывает настройки, и так далее. 2. Если у вас есть сервис по работе с окнами, то через него вы и должны открывать все окна, включая главное. То есть, регистрируете сервис, в нем все VM и окна, затем получаете  сервис, получаете нужную VM, открываете главное окно, готово.



Реализация "сервиса окон" у вас должна быть не такой, как в том ответе, а с учетом контейнера, который вы используете. Сейчас вы изобретаете свой контейнер. Вам надо переписать там код так, чтобы при регистрации окна, эти типы добавлялись в контейнер, а при открытии окна, типы брались из контейнера и открывалось окно. Тогда контейнер будет работать как надо, будет сам пробрасывать все зависимости, и тогда у вас не возникло такого вопроса вовсе. 4. Окна в 2024.... Как по мне, это устаревшая концепция. Все приложения сейчас имеют 1, максимум 2 окна, в которых просто меняется контент.


@EvgeniyZ, понял, попробую сварганить)

При использовании di все получайте через IServiceCollection. Я не знаю, где у вас OpenSettingBD() (будем считать, что в неком MainViewModel), передавайте в этот класс инстанс SettingBDViewModel тоже через di, не используйте new(). То есть там будет код типа такого:
class MainViewModel
{
   private readonly SettingsBDViewModel _sBDVM;
   
   public MainViewModel(SettingsBDViewModel vm)
   {
      _sBDVM = vm;
   }

   void OpenSettingsBD()
   {
      _windowService.ShowModalView(_sBDVM);
   }
}

Либо делайте фабрику для VM диалоговых окошек и внедряйте через di уже её.
